# What is the best normalized way of storing data where titles are subject to change

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, normalization

I have a table that will hold 'game stats'. The name of the stats that are held are going to be changing depending on which sport the stats are for.

Is best practice to make two tables: one for the stats with columns such as 'Stat1, Stat2' etc. and another one holding the titles with the sportID as a key. Or would the best practise to have several tables for resorts for each sport. Or any other way?

Thanks,

Comment: From my experience, the stats of different sports could hardly be represented using a single DB structure. So I'd probably go with separate DB per sport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with andy. A generic-titled column like `Stat1` - where the purpose is unspecified in the column name, is used polymorphically, or the column type must be made more generic - usually indicates a poor SQL/RA design.

Consider if this were encountered: `create table people (field1 varchar(20), field2 varchar(20))`. Yeah - *not* going to fly in my database. Give the columns (and tables) names that mean something in relation to purpose.

Instead, each different *type* of information collected should have it's own entity (read: table) or group of related entities. In this case I would imagine that each sport represents a different type of collected stats/information. (Even Win/Loss information can vary by sport.)

Trying to "label" columns based on an additional table is a half-way attempt of an [Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) model. While an EAV *can* be useful it comes with *a lot* of downsides in SQL and should not be used except after very careful consideration for a specific use-case. (I do *not* believe that EAV fits this scenario appropriately.)

Comment: The thing is, if i do one per table, then i'd need to make around 100 tables. I think EAV may be the way

Comment: @LiamHT EAV is not the way for this. I promise (as much as I can in a comment on stackoverflow..). There will be lots of weeping and gnashing of teeth (especially when trying to build appropriate/useful queries!), but it *is* a path.. I would consider using a template/generator for creation of the tables and a relevant DAL to access them. That is, the dynamic / mapping layer can (and usually should) be moved *outside* of the model itself.

Comment: I'll think it over, thanks for your help

Comment: I think I got an alternative to work, which is quite interesting.

I started by creating a stats table, which has a simple id and name, aswell as a description just incase I decided to list the rules here. The idea is to have a row for each sport's stat, and not cross reference between multiple sports. for the descriptions purpose

I used an existing fixture table to link to a new 'fixture players table' - giving me a list of who was playing in which game.

From there I can then create a ResultStats table, which can reference the playerfixture ID.